# changing value using sed in xml file

Tags: xml, sed, scripting

I want to change port in following input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>SSH</short>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
</service>
```

I tried following command without success:

```
sed "s|\("^[[:space:]]*.+port[[:space:]]+protocol=.+port="\).*|\1\"3022\"\/>|" inputfile
```

but it does no change.

When I grep -E it return correct line and high-light correct matching:

```
# grep -E '^[[:space:]]*.+port[[:space:]]+protocol=.+port=' inputfile
  <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
```

Why sed does not do the job?

Update: I found another command to achieve this:

```
sed -E '/short/,/service/  s/port=[^<]*/port=\"3022\"\/>/' inputfile
```

Comment: Have you tried `sed` with the `-E` flag, like you did with `grep`?

Comment: yes, it returns then error "sed: -e expression #1, char 68: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS"

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why sed does not do the job?

Because `sed` regex and `grep` regex are different, as to which characters you have to escape to get the same meaning. In `sed` `+` means literal `+`, I think you want:

```
sed 's|\(^[[:space:]]*.\+port[[:space:]]\+protocol=.\+port=\).*|\1"3022"/>|'
```

whereas in extended POSIX regular expression `\(` means literal `(`, wheres `(` starts a group:

```
sed -E 's|(^[[:space:]]*.+port[[:space:]]+protocol=.+port=).*|\1"3022"/>|'
```

Note I also changed quoting from `"` to `'` for easier escaping.